# Where does Android keep app permissions?

Tags: permissions

I have a rooted Android, and I want to disable (not read/write/execute) permissions to an app (for example, I don't want it accessing the camera or the phone).

Where does Android keep those permissions? Is it in a database somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

App permissions are defined in the code of the application (the manifest to be exact) and cannot be changed without actually "un-building", changing and then rebuilding the apk again.
the solution you're looking for is using permissions controlling/restricting applications.

Here are some examples for these kind of apps:

[LBE Privacy Guard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbe.security.lite)

[PDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.privacy.pdroid)

[App Ops - Permission Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.msd.permissionmanager)

Answer (score 0):

`/data/system/packages.xml` is the file you want. For each package it follows a template. For an app it would look like this:

```
<package name="com.spazedog.xposed.additionsgb" codePath="/data/app/com.spazedog.xposed.additionsgb-2.apk" nativeLibraryPath="/data/app-lib/com.spazedog.xposed.additionsgb-2" flags="572996" ft="14f1b3d2848" it="14f1b348243" ut="14f1b3d30a2" version="71" userId="10120">
<sigs count="1">
<cert index="20" />
</sigs>
<perms>
<item name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<item name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<item name="net.dinglisch.android.tasker.PERMISSION_RUN_TASKS" />
</perms>
```

You're after the entries between `<perms>` and `</perms>`.